# use ckeditor in bootbox

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, bootbox

is there a way that I can use ckeditor as the textarea within a bootbox dialog? I am using bootbox for other areas with inputs but the only bit I cannot get to work is the textarea. The textarea does show in the dialog, but it is not replaced with ckeditor. Any help with this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by loading the form with the textarea into the bootbox dialog using AJAX.
I just needed to include the following in my ajax response.

```
<script>CKEDITOR.replaceAll(function( textarea, config )</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this:

```
CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.textarea(dialog, elementDefinition, htmlList)
```

or visit here:http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.textarea.html

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is very useful. I ended up just loading the whole form via AJAX... that worked for me.